# AWS, RDS. restoring instance from snapshot stucks in pending-apply in Option Group for hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, snapshot, rds

Please help me to understand what am I doing wrong.
I'm trying to restore db instance from snapshot.
Seems like restoring happens fast but modifying phase gets stuck for hours.
As I can see it cannot apply **Option Group** for new instance - it gets stuck with status **Pending-Apply** for hours.
As I understand it should take only minutes to complete restoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it didn't get stuck. It was converting storage type from IOPS to GP2. It's time consuming operation. When I left storage type without changes restoring operation took about 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the log files? what kind of database is? I had a similar issue with mysql and it was because a innodb datafile was corrupt. I solved it forcing to recover it setting the parameter force_innodb_recovery=1, but be careful    because you can lost data.

Comment: Yes it is mysql and logs are clean - no error messages.